# Is there any such thing as a linear panel meter?

Tags: meter

I like to use regular [panel meters](http://www.adafruit.com/products/252) for showing data. I would like to know if there's such a thing as a **linear** meter, say 10 cm long or so. By linear I mean that the indicator moves up some scale in a linear fashion - like a bar graph, or something similar. Such a meter would likely take up a bit less space on the front panel of a case, and would likely have a pleasing "look and feel".

Do such "linear" meters exist as a manufactured product?

Comment: You mention bargraphs and this, it seems is what you have described. The pleasing look and feel is open to judgement.

Comment: @Andyaka is your comment missing a link?

Comment: @JohnO I think Andy is wondering why you aren't simply using an LED bargraph. Does it have to be an analog meter?

Comment: Do you mean meters where the needle is "L" shaped and its pivot axis is parallel to the front of the display?  I've seen those, but I don't know how common they are nowadays.  They save space on the exterior of a case, but are somewhat bulky inside it.

Comment: @us2012 That's my preference, yes. I would only use an LCD if the analog option isn't possible.

Comment: "Example" here: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Corbomite_Maneuver_%28episode%29 and scan for "Engineering Station Readout" (I can't believe I'm using a Star Trek reference!)

Comment: @supercat No, I don't think so.

Comment: I wasn't talking about hi-res LCD devices, but simple LED bargraphs: http://store.curiousinventor.com/blue-led-bargraph.html . Add a nice front plate to that, and you're fairly close - unless you want it to be 'smooth' (i.e. discrete LEDs don't have enough resolution), in which case an LCD with a nice front plate would be the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: @us2012 The LED bargraph is interesting as an option; though, as you say, it's pretty low resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are sometimes called "[edgewise panel meters](https://www.google.com/search?q=edgewise+panel+meter)"

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's very close to what I was thinking of. Excellent.

Comment: The really cool ones have an indicator that's stationary, and move the scale behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a graphic LCD, then you could draw whatever you want.

Products like the [EarthLCD ez301](http://earthlcd.com) (no affiliation) make this pretty easy with built in scripts for drawing meters of all types. The unit can also accept low voltage analog signals and convert to digital (it has a microcontroller on-board).

Other companies make similar products in different sizes.

[image]

Comment: This is certainly an option. But, aesthetically, my preference is for an electromechanical device if possible.